# external css linking issue

Tags: css

I am new to website development. I am having problem linking my external css to my index page.

This is the structure of my website.

[image: structure]

and I tried to link to my external css using this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css"/>
```

but I keep on getting error in Google Chrome as such[image: error]

The path shown are the correct path of the css file. What have I done wrong? By the way, I am doing this on localhost using MAMP. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

"Restart the MAMP and try it on different path seems to work now. Thanks for all the help."

Comment: Just going to ask the obvious, if this is running on a local server, have you got a copy of the css file on the server as well as where you are working locally?

Comment: put the css folder inside your public_html folder

Comment: yes i did. by putting the http://localhost:8888/advert/user_site/css/main.css in the url bar, i can access to the css file.

Comment: Its originally refers from `/advert/user_site/css/main.css` but your implement is like `/css/main.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the MAMP and try it on different path seems to work now. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking most websites in LAMP reside inside the public_html directory, so everything you want externally accessible should go inside that. i.e move the css and the images folder inside public_html

Answer (score 0):

May be the css file has some permission related issue.

Or

Try by giving absolute url that always works.